# What does "Error: Universe inconsistency" mean in Coq?

Tags: compiler-errors, coq, church-encoding

I am working through [Software Foundations](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/) and am currently doing the exercises on Church numerals.  Here is the type signature of a natural number:

```coq
Definition nat := forall X : Type, (X -> X) -> X -> X.
```

I have defined a function `succ` of type `nat -> nat`.  I would now like to define an addition function like so:

```coq
Definition plus (n m : nat) : nat := n nat succ m.
```

However, I get the following error message:

```coq
Error: Universe inconsistency.
```

What does this error message actually mean?

Comment: You can pass the `-type-in-type` flag to Coq to disable all universe consistency checks. Using this flag is dangerous because it enables Girard's paradox (explained [here](http://www.konne.me/2015/08/17/paradoxes.html)).

Comment: Note that `-type-in-type` only works for Coq 8.5 beta (not for the currently stable 8.4 version)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Coq, everything has a type. `Type` is no exception: if you ask Coq with the `Check` command, it will tell you that its type is... `Type`!

Actually, this is a bit of a lie. If you ask for more details by issuing the directive `Set Printing Universes.`, Coq will tell you that that `Type` is not the same as the first one, but a "bigger" one. Formally, every `Type` has an index associated to it, called its universe level. This index is not visible when printing expressions usually. Thus, the correct answer for that question is that `Type_i` has type `Type_j`, for any index `j > i`. This is needed to ensure the consistency of Coq's theory: if there were only one `Type`, it would be possible to show a contradiction, similarly to how one gets a contradiction in set theory if you assume that there is a set of all sets.

To make working with type indices easier, Coq gives you some flexibility: no type has actually a fixed index associated with it. Instead, Coq generates one new index variable every time you write `Type`, and keeps track of internal constraints to ensure that they can be instantiated with concrete values that satisfy the restrictions required by the theory.

The error message you saw means that Coq's constraint solver for universe levels says that there can't be a solution to the constraint system you asked for. The problem is that the `forall` in the definition of `nat` is quantified over `Type_i`, but Coq's logic forces `nat` to be itself of type `Type_j`, with `j > i`. On the other hand, the application `n nat` requires that `j <= i`, resulting in a non-satisfiable set of index constraints.

Comment: Is there a way to define plus by iterating the succ function, as OP was trying to do, and have it typecheck? The only way I managed to do it was by inlining the definitions of succ and zero, and the result looked absolutely horrible.

Comment: @hugomg Add `Set Universe Polymorphism.` before `nat`'s definition. That should solve the problem.

Comment: @hugomg Instead of defining addition as `n succ m`, you can define it as `λ f. λ x. n f (m f x)`.

Comment: sure, but you can't do something similar with exponentiation. You have to define it as iterated multiplication.

Comment: @hugomg You can define exponentiation *without* iterated multiplication. See the [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding) entry on Wikipedia. It's almost the same in Coq, you just need to figure out the type parameters.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Could you say more about how to avoid iterated multiplication? I've tried for a bit now but cannot figure out how to tweak the type parameters.

Comment: @LeonidR `Definition exp (n m : nat) : nat := fun X => m (X -> X) (n X).` Actually, Coq can infer the type arguments, i.e. the following also works `Definition exp (n m : nat) : nat := fun X => m _ (n _).`.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thank you! Now I understand that Coq's type inferences is more subtle (powerful) than what I'm used to.