# Type : Type in Coq

Tags: coq

By accident, I found that one can make the following definition in Coq:

```
Definition x := Type : Type.
```

What does `Type : Type` mean? What are some use cases for such definition?

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to this answer.

### What does `Definition x := y : A` mean?

This means that `x` is defined to be `y` and there is an assertion that `y` is of type `A`. Usually, this assertion is superfluous because Coq is able to determine the type of `y` just by itself. However, sometimes a term has too many implicit parts, so the assertion is needed in order to determine all those implicit parts.

### What does `Type : Type` mean?

An example of having implicit parts is `Type`. It may come as a surprise to you that there isn't a single `Type` in Coq. Instead there is an infinite hierarchy of types `Type@{0}`, `Type@{1}`, `Type@{2}`… with `Type@{i} : Type@{j}` if `i < j`. This means that every universe (`Type@{j}`) contains every universe with a smaller level as an element.

However, by default, Coq doesn't explicitly show these "universe levels". Coq is usually smart enough that it can figure out the universe levels (or make them generic) without bothering you at all. You can tell Coq to show them with the vernacular command `Set Printing Universes.` or by setting the option in the IDE menu if you're using that. Then, after defining `x` as you did, using the command `Print x.` will display

```
x = 
Type@{Top.2}
     : Type@{Top.1}
(* {Top.2 Top.1} |= Top.2 < Top.1
                     *)
```

So `x` is defined to be `Type@{Top.2}` and has type `Type@{Top.1}`. `Top.1` and `Top.2` are just names for generic universe levels. The part of the message at the bottom is simply stating that `Top.2` must be less than `Top.1`. This is because we need `Type@{Top.2}` to have the type `Type@{Top.1}`. Remember that universes contain the universes below them, but not the ones above them.

### Side question: Why are there multiple levels of `Type`?

In short, if we only had a single `Type` with `Type : Type`, it would be possible to show that the system is inconsistent. This is called Girard's paradox (or a simpler variant known as Hurkens' paradox). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51047212/4639273) for some nice details.

If you want another explanation of Coq's universes, see [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32156394/4639273).

Comment: So is the definition equivalent to `Definition x : Type = Type.` ? I already had some familiarity with universes, but I think my main confusion was from the fact that `: Type` was at the end. I thought that was some special syntax for `Type` types, but now that I tried with other regular types it seems that the "colon type" part can go at the end or before the `:=`, for example `Definition x := 1 : nat.
Definition y : nat := 1.`

Comment: @yewang There might be some edge cases where the two are different (I don't know the technical details of Coq's unifier). But yes, in general the two should be the same.